# How to log stock?

Tags: 9

How could I create a log where the records of the stock level in D9 are kept, just as I have done on my D7 page?

This is that I,ve got on D7

[image]

In D7 use a View like that[image]

Using the Rules module with custom PHP code:

```
$ref = $commerce_product->sku;
$stock_final = $commerce_product->commerce_stock[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
$message = 'Producto creado - Ref. ' . $ref . ' con un stock inicial de ' . $stock_inicial . ' unidades.';
watchdog('registro_stock', $message, NULL, WATCHDOG_INFO, NULL);
```

I can't use this in D9 because I can't export this rule using the Rules Module for D9.

Any suggestions for this?

[image]

Comment: Anything implemented by the Rules module in D7 can be implemented directly in a custom module in D9 (without using the Rules module).  To help you further, you need to share the full rule (what is the trigger?)

Comment: Okey, thanks bro. I share a screenshot with the full rule above that. The event fires 'After saving a new product' any advice? Thanks in advance.